# R3 Corda distributed system

Tags: distributed-system, corda

I want to create two nodes in R3 Corda in my computer and two nodes in another computer and want to communicate from one node in my computer  to another in another computer.How do I achieve this in R3 Corda?

Answer (score 1):

For development purposes, you can easily set up a Corda network across machines by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-nodes-across-machines.

To set up a full, non-devmode network, take a look at the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/setting-up-a-corda-network.html.